# Pointer Matrix in C

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, parameters

I am trying to execute the following code

```
static double** updateA(double f_x0,double f_x1,double f_x2){
    double a[3][3] = {{f_x0*f_x0, f_x0, 1},{f_x1*f_x1, f_x1, 1},{f_x2*f_x2, f_x2, 1}};

    return a;
}
static double** updateAc (double f_x0,double f_x1,double f_x2, double x0,double x1,double x2){
    double ac[3][3] = {{f_x0*f_x0, f_x0, x0},{f_x1*f_x1, f_x1, x1},{f_x2*f_x2, f_x2, x2}};
    return ac;
}

static double det3x3 (double** a){
    return (a[0][0]*((a[1][1]*a[2][2]) - (a[2][1]*a[1][2])) - a[0][1]*(a[1][0]
   * a[2][2] - a[2][0]*a[1][2]) + a[0][2]*(a[1][0]*a[2][1] - a[2][0]*a[1][1]));
}

static double newx2 (double f_x0,double f_x1,double f_x2, double x0,double x1,double x2){
    double **ac = updateAc(f_x0, f_x1, f_x2, x0, x1, x2);
    double **a = updateA(f_x0, f_x1, f_x2);
    double c = det3x3(ac)/det3x3(a);

    return c;
}
```

However it is not working, it compiles with the following warning:

incompatible pointer types returning 'double [3][3]' from
a function with result type 'double **'

But when I try to execute the code it doesn't work. I am using gcc as compiler.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you in advance,

Lucas

Comment: Executing that code will fail for lack of a main() function. Consider creating a [mre].

Comment: `return a;` You are retruning a pointer to an automatic ("stack*) variabble here.

Comment: There is a main but it is not relevant for the problem, once everything else is working, the problem is between the parameters being send from newx2 to det3x3 (that were received from updateA and updateAc)

Comment: @wildplasser yes, it is coherent with the compiler message, but what's the correct to do it?

Comment: Simplest way is to let the caller allocate, and pass the matrix argument by a pointer. (this will also allow the compiler to inline the complete function, BTW)

Comment: @wildplasser you mean like that:
double ac = updateAc(f_x0, f_x1, f_x2, x0, x1, x2);
...
double c = det3x3(&&ac)/det3x3(&&a);

Comment: That you return a pointer to a local variable which has disappeared by the time the return value is used is an independent problem from the type error. It would persist (and bite you) even if you got the types right.

Comment: Another *clean* way is to embed the 3*3 matrix in a struct, and pass a pointer to this struct. This can also be inlined. The 3x3 sizes must stay fixed, though.

Comment: Like the compile error says, you can't pass a `double [3][3]` to function det3x3() expecting `double **`. The signature should instead be `double det3x3(double (*a)[3])`. As others have mentioned, functions updateA() and updateAc() return [dangling pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) and will lead to invalid memory accesses and confusing bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the *struct method*.

- Only works for fixed sizes (in this case : 3*3)
- the sizes are hard-coded
- the caller (in this case `main()` allocates, and passes a pointer.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct nine {
        double data[3][3];
        };

void do_it(struct nine *p)
{
p->data[0][0] = 0.0;
// ..
}

int main(void)
{
struct nine this9 = {{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}};

do_it( &this9 );
printf("%lf\n", this9.data[0][0] );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note: there are other *solutions* to this *problem*.